# Find Selected Attribute Options

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, layered-navigation

I'm fairly new to Magento, so apologies if this has been answered before and I just haven't been able to find it. I'm currently working with a client who requires bulk product imports, but their sizes aren't particularly user friendly. To get around this I created a secondary size attribute for the store front end which can be selected manually.

The front end is displaying these values fine, so what I'm looking for now is a way to access a list of which attribute options have been selected by products so that I can build a filtration system using it (eg if there are no medium products in stock then the "medium" size won't appear in the attribute option array)

Thanks for any help you can give

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your new size attribute set option "used in layered navigation" to "yes, filterable with results" and reindex.

Comment: Trying that now. I'd actually changed the value already, but hadn't thought to reindex when it didn't show up on the front end

Comment: Yep, that seems to have done it. Thanks for the help